# Strange behavior in dplyr when mapping language vector on tm::stopwords

Tags: r, dplyr, tm, stop-words, qdap

I want to extract stop words for several languages in one `dplyr` pipeline using this code:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(qdap)
    library(tm)
    map_dfr(tibble(language=c("english", "italian")), tm::stopwords)
```

Which gives me uninformative error message:

`Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(resolved)) kind else if (identical(resolved, "porter")) "english" else resolved :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Can some one explain this and suggest work around. I would like to have tibble where each row corresponds to language title and respective list (vector) of stop words?

Comment: `map`ing over a data.frame will iterate over columns. Instead I *think* you want to map over the elements in language and return a list column for each. So `tibble(language=c("english", "italian")) %>% 
         mutate(stop_words = map(language, tm::stopwords))` instead

Comment: or maybe `c("english", "italian") %>% set_names() %>% map_dfr(~tibble(stop_words = tm::stopwords(.)), .id = "lang")` for one big data frame

Comment: Both solutions worked, but in my case the first one was more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not looping as intended.  The unit here is a single column.  We need to extract the column and loop

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- map(tibble(language=c("english", "italian"))$language, ~ tm::stopwords(.x))
```

---

Or another option is

```
tibble(language=c("english", "italian")) %>% 
   mutate(stop_words = Vectorize(stopwords)(language))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   language stop_words  
#  <chr>    <named list>
#1 english  <chr [174]> 
#2 italian  <chr [279]>
```